# Update reference variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, reference

Just wondering if it's possible to update object reference variables if variable is a string? It works, if I assign the whole object, but doesn't work with the string. I could assign also the whole object, but the issue here is that I don't need an object, but I need a string, since it's a global variable of Angular 2 service.

https://jsfiddle.net/009kqqrt/

```
obj = { var: 'initial' };
a = [{ test: 'old', new: 'no' }, { test: obj.var, new: 'yes' }];
o = { test: obj.var, new: 'yes' };

obj.var = 'objModified';

alert(o.test); // Changes correctly

obj.var = 'arrModified';

alert(a[1].test);
```

Here is the jsfiddle.

Expected result would be -

first alert - 'objModified'
second alert - 'arrModified'

In my case, I get always 'initial'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is pass the object reference

```
var obj = { var: 'initial' };
var a = [{ test: 'old', new: 'no' }, { test: obj, new: 'yes' }];
var o = { test: obj, new: 'yes' };

obj.var = 'objModified';

alert(o.test.var); // Changes correctly

obj.var = 'arrModified';

alert(o.test.var);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/echonax/009kqqrt/2/

If you pass the string reference like, `test: obj.var` since strings are immutable, it won't change.

Comment: Okay, so there are no possibility to change the value without passing the object with the reference?

Comment: @VdasDorls you can iterate over the array and change it manually

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it **a** and **o** objects reference the value of the **obj.var** at the time when they are created.

Any changes to that value after they are created are not going to propagate to **a** and **o**.

If you want it to work that way you will need to make the **test** property reference an object instead of referencing the value directly.

```js
obj = { var: 'initial' };
a = [{ test: 'old', new: 'no' }, { test: obj, new: 'yes' }];
o = { test: obj, new: 'yes' };

obj.var = 'objModified'; 

alert(o.test.var); // o.test=== obj is true

obj.var = 'arrModified';

alert(a[1].test.var); // a[1].test=== obj is true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the array `a` and the object `o`, the properties `test` are initialized with the value of a simple string variable, so theirs values are stored "as value".

```
obj = { var: 'initial' };
a = [{ test: 'old', new: 'no' }, { test: obj.var, new: 'yes' }];
o = { test: obj.var, new: 'yes' };
```

If you initialize that with an object reference, like following example:

```js
var obj = { var: 'initial' };
a = [{ test: 'old', new: 'no' }, { test: obj, new: 'yes' }];
o = { test: obj, new: 'yes' };

obj.var = 'objModified';
console.log(o.test.var);
obj.var = 'arrModified';
console.log(a[1].test.var);
```

You could see that theirs value will modified when the referenced object is modified, that's because theirs value is stored by reference.

I hope it was clear, bye.